# ISubscription to be passed in CreateFlow method for ITopicEndpoint

Tags: solace

I am creating a Flow instance for a ITopicEndpoint, the documentation says that ISubscription should be passed to the createFlow method only if endpoint is of type ISubscriberEndpoint.

> From the documentation 
>   subscription Type:
>   SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.ISubscription Only valid if endpoint
>   is of type ISubscriberEndpoint.

**I am creating a Flow for a ITopicEndpoint so why am I getting the below error**. What should i pass for ISubscription?

System.ArgumentException: 'subscription must be non-null when endpoint is of type ITopicEndpoint'

```
topic = ContextFactory.Instance.CreateDurableTopicEndpointEx(topicName);
flow = session.CreateFlow(flowProps, topic, null, HandleFlowMessageEvent, HandleFlowEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a durable topic endpoint, if you have multiple subscribers then each would have to register with a unique subscription name so that the broker can maintain a durable connection with the specific subscriber. Even if the subscriber is down for a while and reconnects, it will not loose out on messages in the interim. The broker will push the messages to the subscriber.

You can create a subscriber  via the Solace Admin client or via code. 
Solace Admin -> Select the VPN -> Choose Endpoint tab -> select Durable Topic Endpoint -> click the + sign to create a subscriber -> ensure that consume is chosen for 'All other Permissions'